# Is it possible to replace Jackrabbit repository with Community File Repository in Pentaho BI Server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

We are using Pentaho BI Server for mainly scheduling Jobs and Transformations. Drawback of Jackrabbit is that you cannot refer to additional files (.csv, .txt etc) with in your transformation using parameter **${Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}**, you can refer to transformations or jobs with that though.

Community File Repository doesn't have this restriction as it saves files as it is. The [documentation](https://github.com/webdetails/cfr) for CFR states

> An easy way for a user to upload some files to the BA Server (maybe to
>   be used by an ETL job)

however there are no examples of how to do it !! But my question, is it even possible to switch to CFR, I have googled to find any help but unfortunately there are none that were helpful. 
Looked at **pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\repository.spring.xml** file which supposedly defines repository classes but not sure what changes will enable CFR.. ???

If anyone knows how to achieve this it will be

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Any specific reason you are using BI server for scheduling?
You can use windows task schedular incase of window and crontab incase of Linux.

Comment: We have fairly large implementation of Pentaho with lots of access control features, users from different departments can manage schedules, log, report, source control workflows and provide permissions.  Initially we did create our own version of web service  utilizing the command line method (spinning up kitchen/pan upon user request and managing other feature by ourselves) but soon it became too complicated with all the various features and we thought its best bet to use BI server as it provide many of the features we need out of box plus some additional functionality to scale.